# Two circles with perpendicular outer and common inner tangent(s) from the origin

Tags: circles

This question was briefly on MSE yesterday, asked by someone else.

If we have two circles $$(x-x(A))^2+(y-y(A))^2=r_1^2$$ $$(x-x(B))^2+(y-y(B))^2=r_2^2$$ tangent at $C$ with the common tangent line going through the origin then the other tangents from the origin have segments  from the origin to the tangent points $D, E$ equal and equal to $\sqrt{x(A)^2+y(A)^2-r_1^2}=\sqrt{x(B)^2+y(B)^2-r_2^2},$ the square root of the constant term in the expanded equations.

[image: circletangentsfromorigin]

Now if the other tangents are perpendicular

[image: perp]

then the question is to prove

> $|x(A)x(B)+y(A)y(B)|=|x(A)y(B)-y(A)x(B)|.$

My attempt: I have verified it using geogebra for a varying line and varying point $A$ on the bisector line, the rest (B on the other bisector line and the perpendicular line from A through the circle tangent point) being determined by the constraints. The strategy has been to look for areas, hoping two would be the same and give the identity, finding

[image: area]

Now this is $|x(A)y(B)-y(A)x(B)|,$ and using the auxiliary circle through the origin, $A,B,C,D,E;$ $|x(A)|=|y(B)|$ and $|x(A)x(B)+y(A)y(B)|=|\pm |y(B)|x(B)+y(A)y(B)|=|y(B)||\pm |x(B)|\pm |y(A)||.$ It seems I need a new idea to get over the finish line.

**Edit**

From QEDs answer I see that what needs to be proven is $|x(A)y(B)-y(A)x(B)|=2\cdot \operatorname{Area}(\triangle{OAB}),$ but I don't see why I can take $B$ to be the midpoint on the square of $|y(B)|.$

Anyway, WLOG I can scale to axis-aligned square of side $1$ cut away its upper right corner: [image: square] $\operatorname{Area}(\triangle{OAB})=1-(\frac12 (1-x(B))(1-y(A))+\frac12 x(B)+\frac12 y(A))$ so $2\cdot \operatorname{Area}(\triangle{OAB})=1-x(B)y(A)$ and we're done.

Comment: $B$ is the midpoint of the square because because the side on which $B$ lies is the diameter of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call the radius of the circle centered at $A$ as $r_A=|y(A)|$ and the radius of the circle centered at $B$ be $r_B=|x(B)|$. Let the length of the common tangent be $T=|x(A)|=|y(B)|$. Then we see that $|x(B)y(B)+x(A)y(A)|=T.(r_A+r_B)=2.\mathrm{area}(OAB)$. Your problem is basically reduced to this:

> For a square $ABCD$, let $E$ be the midpoint of $CD$ and $F$ be a point on $BC$. Also $EI\parallel AD$, $FG\parallel AB$, and $EI$ and $FG$ intersect at $H$. Then prove $$\mathrm{area}(ABCD)-\mathrm{area}(AIHG)=2.\mathrm{area}(AFE)$$
> [image]

This is a much simpler problem and quite easy to handle. Can you solve it?